# NEX-GDDP-CMIP6 exporting data

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I have been using this code to export data for the NEX-GDDP product, but for the new NEX-GDDP-CMPI6 it doesn't work

This is the code:

```
var startDate = ee.Date('2018-01-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2019-01-01');

// get the dataset between date range and extract band on interest
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/NEX-GDDP')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate,endDate));

// get projection and band information
var firstImage = dataset.first();
var bandNames = firstImage.bandNames();
var proj = firstImage.projection();

var point = ee.Geometry.Point([-71.689166667, -13.921388889])

// calculate number of days to map and extract data for
var n = endDate.difference(startDate,'day').subtract(1);

// map over each date and extract all climate model values
var timeseries = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0,n).map(function(i){
    var t1 = startDate.advance(i,'day');
    var t2 = t1.advance(1,'day');
    var dailyColl = dataset.filterDate(t1, t2);
    var dailyImg = dailyColl.toBands();
    // rename bands to handle different names by date
    var bands = dailyImg.bandNames();
    var renamed = bands.map(function(b){
      var split = ee.String(b).split('_');
      return split.slice(0,2).cat(split.slice(-1)).join('_');
    });
    // extract the data for the day and add time information
    var dict = dailyImg.rename(renamed).reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: point,
      scale: proj.nominalScale()
    }).combine(
      ee.Dictionary({'system:time_start':t1.millis(),'isodate':t1.format('YYYY-MM-dd')})
    );
    return ee.Feature(point,dict);
  })
);
print(timeseries);

// get properties to chart (all climate models)
var props = timeseries.first().propertyNames().removeAll(['system:time_start','system:index','isodate']);

// Make a chart of the results.
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(timeseries, 'system:time_start', props.getInfo());
print(chart);
    
Map.addLayer(point);
Map.centerObject(point,6);

// export feature collection to CSV
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: timeseries,
  description: 'NEX-GDDP-timeseries',
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
})`
```

This is the error:

`Error: Image.rename: Can't add a band named 'historical_GFDL-CM4_hurs' to image because a band with this name already exists. Existing bands: [historical_ACCESS-CM2_hurs, historical_ACCESS-CM2_huss,.......`

I think it is maybe because of the new bands added. Also, the historical period was changed to 2014, I tried to export the year 2014 but the error also happened. The bands needed are only pr, tasmax and tasmin.